# How to return specific object values related to privacy values?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have this mongoose model:

```
var user = new Schema({
email   : {type: String},
firstName: {type: String},
lastName: {type: String},
username: {type:String},
password: {type:String},
privacy : {
  displayEmail: {type: Boolean, default: true},
  displayUsername: {type:Boolean: default: true},
  displayfirstName: {type:Boolean: default: true},
  displaylastName: {type:Boolean: default: true}
})
```

Let's assume that the user sets the value of `displayEmail` abd `displayLastName` to `false`.

Then, I have a simple GET request that returns a json object with all the users details. How can I query mongo to return only the fields that have `true` in the privacy object? If `displayfirstName` is true, then the `firstName` value should be returned.

**Update**

```
var user = new Schema({
email     : {type: String},
firstName : {type: String},
lastName  : {type: String},
username  : {type:String},
password  : {type:String},
privacy : {
  displayEmail     : {type: Boolean, default: true},
  displayUsername  : {type:Boolean, default: true},
  displayfirstName : {type:Boolean, default: true},
  displaylastName  : {type:Boolean, default: true},
  displayAddress   : {type: Boolean, default: true}, // new 
  displayPhone     : {type: Boolean, default: true}  // new
},
extraInfo : {
     userAddress : {type:String},  // new
     userPhone   : {type: String}  // new
  }
})
```

How i can conditionally check the address and phone field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of is through an aggregation pipeline that has a **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** operator with a **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** expression that evaluates the condition and returns the value of one of the other two expressions depending on the logic evaluated.

Take for instance, running the following pipeline will give
you a document that displays all the fields but their values depend on what the display subdocument fields have; if it's true then the actual value is returned otherwise a null value is returned:

```
User.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "email": {
                "$cond": ["$privacy.displayEmail", "$email", null]
            },
            "firstName": {
                "$cond": ["$privacy.displayfirstName", "$firstName", null]
            },
            "lastName": {
                "$cond": ["$privacy.displaylastName", "$lastName", null]
            },
            "username": {
                "$cond": ["$privacy.displayUsername", "$username", null]
            }
        }
    }
]).exec(function(err, users){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(users, null, 4));
})
```

---

### UPDATE

Following up your other question from the comments, to conditionally check for the `address` and `phone` fields `AND` filter the collection using the id from a `GET` parameter, run the pipeline with a **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** operator which acts as a query and then add the extra info fields conditional display in your **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)**:

```
var userId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId(req.parameter.userId);

User.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "_id": userId } },
    {
        "$project": {
            "email": {
                "$cond": ["$privacy.displayEmail", "$email", null]
            },
            "firstName": {
                "$cond": ["$privacy.displayfirstName", "$firstName", null]
            },
            "lastName": {
                "$cond": ["$privacy.displaylastName", "$lastName", null]
            },
            "username": {
                "$cond": ["$privacy.displayUsername", "$username", null]
            },
            "userAddress": {
                "$cond": ["$privacy.displayAddress", "$extraInfo.userAddress", null]
            },
            "userPhone": {
                "$cond": ["$privacy.displayPhone", "$extraInfo.userPhone", null]
            }
        }
    }
]).exec(function(err, users){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(users, null, 4));
})
```

Comment: i'll check it now and i ll come back with results, thanks!

Comment: thank you for the answer, can you please check the question again, i added another object that needs to be conditionally checked.

Comment: the code returns all users from the database, how i can limit it only to the GET parameter id?

Comment: Avoid changing the question the way you did, it's highly discouraged here on SO. There are meta discussions on this [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252113/how-to-deal-with-constant-changing-questions).

Comment: now it returns an empty array [ ], i console.log the userId and it's fine.

Comment: for some reason, it won't read the `var userId = req.params.userId` (even tho i can console log it fine from the req), i ended up fetching the user and then use `var userId = user._id`. Can't figure out why $match can't assign the userId in first place. What the `null, 4` stands for?

Comment: Try casting the id to `ObjectId` (as in the update). The optional arguments in [**`JSON.stringify()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Parameters) method allows you to format the output of the object, for example `JSON.stringify({a:1,b:2,c:{d:1,e:[1,2]}}, null, 4);` the object will be indented by 4 spaces, `JSON.stringify({a:1,b:2,c:{d:1,e:[1,2]}}, null, "\t");` is indented with a tab.

Comment: cast to `ObjectId` returns the same result, [ ]. I'm fine with the fix i mentioned above.